В БД postgresql сделать выборку строк по нескольким столбцам
Есть след таблица:



uuid
call_id_in
call_id_out




1
111
null


2
666
444


3
222
111


4
777
888



На выходе требуется получить выборку  строк, где call_id_in == call_id_out и новый инкрементируемый  столбец channel_id  - начинается с 1.



channel_id
call_id_in
call_id_out




1
111
222



SELECT 
    call_id_in, call_id_out 
FROM 
    call 
WHERE 
    call_id_in  IN (SELECT call_id_in FROM call  GROUP BY call_id_in)
    AND call_id_out IN (SELECT call_id_out  FROM call)

ORDER by call_id_in; 


Вот так:
select ROW_NUMBER() over() as channel_id, 
    t1.call_id_in as call_id_in, 
    t2.call_id_in as call_id_out
from test1 t1, test1 t2
where t1.call_id_in = t2.call_id_out

И еще - не стоит называть таблицы служебными словами SQL

То что надо, спасибо.

@Mik Если то, что надо, отметьте ответ решением.
